# Hbase shell: how to get records by putting filter on columns

Tags: hbase

I want to make a Hbase shell command to get records having firstname='xyz' and lastname ="zzz" where firstname and lastname are column names of table. 
Please let me know the command how to put filter on columns value?

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm late for this one, 
I'm still new to HBase, 
but still I'd like to suggest you to try this:

```
scan "<tablename>",{
FILTER => 
    "SingleColumnValueFilter('<columnfamily>','firstname',=,'binary:xyz') 
    AND 
    SingleColumnValueFilter('<columnfamily>','lastname',=,'binary:zzz')"
}
```

Tested with Cloudera 5.15.x Hbase shell.